Bernoulli Factory for mean of discrete variable
Suppose $Z$ is a discrete random variable on $\mathbb{N}$ with $P(Z=z)=p_z$ unknown, and $\mathbb{E}[Z]=p$ where $0\leq p \leq 1$ a.s. We can simulate observations of $Z$. Is it possible to construct a Bernoulli Factory for $p$?

I doubt it: you can change $E[Z]$ by an arbitrarily large amount with an arbitrarily small change to $p_z$ on a sufficiently large $z$. In particular, you can choose the $z$ so that it is very unlikely to be sampled.
This suggests that a constraint on $E[Z]$ won't be an effective way to control the output probability.  No, it's not a proof.
